# Resize property for text in html

Tags: jquery, html, css

How to resize text inside a `div` by the user in front end .

for div resizing in the front by the user   we can use css like

```
div {
    resize: both;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

or using jquery

```
$( "#div-id" ).resizable();
```

To edit text in a div in the front we can use

```
<div id="div-id"  contenteditable="true"> Type text</div>
```

But how to make the resizable   text inside a div .

**EXAMPLE:**

User can change the text inside this div  `<div id="div-id"  contenteditable="true"> Type text</div>` , but how user can increase the text size in that div ?.

**Note** :  actually this font size able to change by user . Currently the user can edit the text . In the same way user able to do increase the font size

Thank you

Comment: You would need to use js to change the class of the div or change the font-style - `$( "#div-id" ).css('font-size', '150%')`

Comment: Are you looking for some kind of richtext editor?   https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=richtext%20editor

Comment: check out viewport percentage http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16056591/font-scaling-based-on-width-of-container

Comment: @Pete actually this font size able to change by user . Currently the user can edit the text . In the same way user able to do  increase the font size .

Comment: @Woncker Hi, it's not about viewport width or automatic scaling

Comment: @freedomn-m . No .

Comment: @Ron only if you build a custom control - the only other way to resize your text is to zoom the browser in and out.  There is no native controls for resizing text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can grab on resize event

```
$( function() {
  var basefont = 14;
  var scale = 1;
  var width = $( "#div-id" ).width();
  $( "#div-id" ).resizable();
  $( "#div-id" ).on('resize', function() {
    scale = $(this).width() / width;
    $( "#div-id" ).css('font-size', scale*basefont);
  }); });
```

Example:

https://jsfiddle.net/e3q3zrrk/1/

Comment: Thank you friend . this is the same way i need . I don't know why people down vote this question

Comment: Is it possible to make the width and height of the div according to the text in it ?

Comment: @Ron Obviously yes. Something like `var relativeWidth = $(".mytext").css("font-size"); $("#mydiv").width(relativeWidth);`

Comment: so that user can feel like they are increasing the font size . not by increasing div size .

Answer (score 0):

You can use an increasing / Decreasing variable for the size and some jQuery Font attributes.

```
<a href="#"><p class="myclass">test</p></a>


mySize = 12;
$(this).click(function ()
              {
                mySize = mySize + 2;
                $(".myclass").css("font-size", mySize + "px" );
                console.log(mySize);

});
```

Comment: thank you . I will check this . Could you please give an demo .

Comment: I guess you should be using `$(".myText").css()` method not `$(".myText").attr()` method.

Comment: Absolutely right. I've made some corrections @user31782

Comment: Thank you @CarlosMartins . :)

Answer (score 0):

I second Carlos's suggestion. You could first define how the `mysize` should change when resizing the div like this:

```
var multiplicate = 0.7
var mySize = multiplicate*$( "#div-id" ).width();  
 $(".myText").css( "font-size", mySize + "px");
```

Comment: Thank you  . I will check .

Comment: @Ron Also you will have to put my code in `resize` event. I am not sure jquery resize event works on everything just like on window. Otherwise you could use `setTimeout` or `onmousemove` etc events to execute the code every time div's dimensions chage.

Comment: Friend i didn't understand . what modification need to do in @jaerk answer ?

Comment: @ron jaerk's answer is fine. I didn't read that while writing the comment.

Comment: ok. Could you please check this ? according to your comment i add this code    var relativeWidth = $("#div-id").css("font-size"); 
           $("#div-id").width(relativeWidth);   into $( "#div-id" ).on('resize', function() {}  . and change the css of #div-id . but it's not working .

Comment: I think `$("#div-id").css("font-size")` will in pixels that is like `12px`. You would have to change "12px" string to numeric with `parseInt("mystring")`. Also this will not work with `resize` event because we are now changing the font-size. Perhaps `change` event will work f you are using an `input` field.